# how to differentiate docker container and kubernetes pods running in the same host

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I was handed a kubernetes cluster to manage. But in the same node, I can see running docker containers (via docker ps) that I could not able to find/relate in the pods/deployments (via kubectl get pods/deployments).

I have tried kubectl describe and docker inspect but could not pick out any differentiating parameters.

How to differentiate which is which?

Comment: where is the issue? If there any pods then you will get it by `kubectl get pods`. You got nothing means there is no pod.

Comment: If you destroy a node and create a new one, the new node will probably only have Kubernetes-managed pods.

Comment: show example, we will explain you where from there containers go. E.g, like @coderanger mentioned, here is a bit info  about technical [pause containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020184/difference-between-kubernetes-metrics-metrics-resource-v1alpha1-and-metrics/63520661#63520661)

Answer (score 1):

There will be many. At a minimum you'll see all the pod sandbox pause containers which are normally not visible. Plus possibly anything you run directly such as the control plane if not using static pods.

Comment: I'd add to this that k8s containers are labeled as a Christmas tree.